# modify the existing array object based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How to modify the array object in javascript,

Two array objects `obj1` and `obj2`, in which key value of `title` are same,
then add to the key `details` in javascript.

if title of obj1 and obj2 are same, then add `amt`,`idx` to details key,

```
function modifyArray(obj1, obj2){
   return obj1.map(a1=> {
          return {
            ...a1,
            details: obj2
              .filter(a2=> a2.title=== a1.title)
              .map(a2=> ({ idx: a2.idx, amt: a2.amt|| 0 }))
          }
        })
}

var obj1= [ 
  {id:1, title: "item1", details: [{idx:1, amt: 100},{idx:2, amt: 200}]} 
  {id:2, title: "item2", details: []},
  {id:3, title: "item3" } 
]

var obj2 =[
  { idx:"3", title: "item1", amt: 120},
  { idx:"4", title: "item1", amt: 140},
  { idx:"1", title: "item2", amt: 220},
  { idx:"1", title: "item3", amt: 240},
  { idx:"2", title: "item3", amt: 200}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
 [ 
  {id:1, title: "item1", details: [{idx:1, amt: 100},{idx:2, amt: 200},{idx:3, amt: 120},{idx:4, amt: 140}]} 
  {id:2, title: "item2", details: [{idx:1, amt: 220}]},
  {id:3, title: "item3", details: [{idx:1, amt: 240},{idx:2, amt: 200}] } 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. But try something like this.

```
function comp(obj1, obj2) {
  const final = [];
  obj1.forEach((element1) => obj2.forEach((element2) => {
    if (element1.title == element2.title) {
      final.push({
        id: element1.id,
        title: element1.title,
        details: element1.details || []
      })
    }
  }))
  return final;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be making use of `reduce` by merging both arrays. Here it is:

```js
var obj1= [{id:1, title: "item1", details: [{idx:1, amt: 100},{idx:2, amt: 200}]}, {id:2, title: "item2", details: []}, {id:3, title: "item3" }];

var obj2 =[ { idx:"3", title: "item1", amt: 120}, { idx:"4", title: "item1", amt: 140}, { idx:"1", title: "item2", amt: 220}, { idx:"1", title: "item3", amt: 240}, { idx:"2", title: "item3", amt: 200}];

var result = Object.values([...obj1,...obj2].reduce((acc, elem)=>{
    if(!elem.idx){
     acc[elem.title] = elem.details ? elem : {...elem, details:[]}
     } else {
     acc[elem.title].details.push({idx:elem.idx, amt:elem.amt});
    }
    return acc; 
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks, if obj2 has one more object `{idx:1, title: "item1", amt:100},` same index should not be in resultant obj